# Load OpenLayers library with it's dependencies (Google and OSM) async possible?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, openlayers, openstreetmap

I build a AJAX application and have a dedicated part of my application that uses OpenLayers.

At the moment I have the following in my Application.html file, so it gets included at application start:

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.11/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js"></script>
```

Now I want to load all this stuff when it's needed, because it has about 500-1000kb size. But I don't know how to do it.

**What I've tried:**

1. Load OpenLayers.js and in its callback: ...
2. ... Load GoogleMaps.js and OpenStreetMap.js. And when these both are finished: ...
3. ... Display my map.

Sometimes it works, but most of the time it doesn't, because: GoogleMaps.js and OpenStreetMap.js have some additional .js, .css, .png, etc. dependencies that load independently from my callbacks.

This means: The 3 .js files have finished loading, the callback tells my application to display the map, but in the background those .js files still fetch additional content that's necessary for using OpenLayers.

**Is there a way to solve this problem?**

Comment: Whilst I'm not in favour of cross-posting, if this really is OL specific you may have more success on the GIS exchange site: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

There again, if it isn't OL specific but generic to JS apps, you may be able to re-interpret it as tracking load complete for child js libraries.  If that's the case, then you could switch to a more generic title for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using either of the following approaches or combination of them.

1) https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideHttpRequests

2) https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite

Comment: No and no again... It's no problem to include those external .js files and have a callback when those are loaded. The problem is: These external .js files load other external files, and for those I don't have callbacks. So I don't know when everything(!) finished loading. Example: a.js internally loads b.js. If I put a callback on a.js it fires when a.js finished loading, but at this point of time I have no information about the status of b.js (it may be already loaded or it may take some more time).

Comment: Oops my mistake. I understood the problem now.

Comment: @Ben The question title probably needs to be altered to focus in on the the resource loading problem avoiding reference to technology. +1 on the question though!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try GWT-OpenLayers instead.

https://bitbucket.org/gwtopenlayers/gwt-openlayers

Comment: i already use gwt-openlayers. but it's a general javascript problem ;-)